# How come my DataMapper validations aren't working?

Tags: ruby, datamapper, validation

This example doesn't validate the presence of the title for me:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'dm-core'
require 'dm-migrations'
require 'dm-validations'

db_name = 'rvtest.sqlite'

DataMapper::Logger.new($stdout, :debug)
DataMapper.setup(:default, 'sqlite://' + Dir.pwd + '/' + db_name)

class Task
  include DataMapper::Resource
  property :id,         Serial
  property :title,      String

  validates_presence_of :title
end

DataMapper.finalize
DataMapper.auto_upgrade!
```

However, this one does:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'dm-core'
require 'dm-migrations'
require 'dm-validations'

db_name = 'rvtest.sqlite'

DataMapper::Logger.new($stdout, :debug)
DataMapper.setup(:default, 'sqlite://' + Dir.pwd + '/' + db_name)

class Task
  include DataMapper::Resource
  property :id,         Serial
  property :title,      String, :required => true

end

DataMapper.finalize
DataMapper.auto_upgrade!
```

Why do these work differently?  If I go into irb, require this file and type `Task.new.save!` the first one returns `true` and the second `false`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

save! doesn't call any callbacks, which means it doesn't call validations. try with save

Comment: Hmm, interesting.  So does that mean that the first one validates at the application level and the second one sets database constraints?  Otherwise, both of my examples should save to the database.

Comment: Yes exactly. DB constraints are set based on property declarations, they can also be used by dm-validations to set up auto-validation on the app level of course. In your first example :title field is created without NOT NULL option, so you case save a task with title set to nil. You would get a validation error if you used #save, by using #save! all callbacks are bypassed and since there's no db constraint the resource is persisted. In your second example you use :required => true which results in the title db field with NOT NULL option, so even if you use #save! a task won't be persisted